# if a is a cv::Mat and cv::Mat b=a.row(1),then What is the difference between the two cv::Mat instances?

Tags: c++, opencv

> Mat a = (Mat_(3,3) << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
>   cv::Mat b=a.row(1);

`cv::Mat` has a field called `data`, that is a pointer which is pointed to the actual memory for the Mat.
I know this is shallow copy, no new memory will be allocated to store the elements in `a.row(1)` for `b` .
`a` and `b` will share a same piece of memory.
And the `data` field of `b` will be the same as `a` 's `data` field.

My question is:
if The `data` field of `b` is the same as `a` 's `data` field, then what is the difference between `a` and `b` ?
Their `data` fields are the same , but other functions know `a` and `b` are different !!
How do they know this?

Comment: What is M in that context ? You forgot a couple of lines to make it understandable, although I think I know where this is going..

Comment: edited.. could you tell me what is going on inside the two cv::Mat?

Comment: Sorry, some typos... and now ,fixed.. Could you help me with this question ?

Comment: if you compare them by reference in the function, they will be seen as having a different address, and therefore different. If you compare them by value (and for that you would need to overload the == operator), then they will be seen as identical.
Think about it, if I show you 2 black cats, and I ask you "are they the same ?" you'll say "well no, I can tell they are two different cats".
Now if I specify that we compare their color and their race, you will say "Yes they are exactly the same".

Comment: Maybe the distinction between a and b is for the right hand side of equations.

Comment: Thx , @Miche But Maybe I didn't clarify my question. I mean the function will treat `a` as a 3*3 matrix, but treat `b` as a 1*3 matrix. Although their `data` fields are the same. What I mean is that ... I wonder what other fields in `cv::Mat` help to determine this.

Comment: Thank you both.. I found out why...My per-assumption is wrong!!

Answer (score 1):

My assumption was wrong !
Although no new memory is allocated, the `data` fields of `a` and `b` are different!!

Here's a snippet code of the headers in `mat.hpp`,where `cv::Mat` is defined as this:

```
class CV_EXPORTS Mat
{
public:
    // ... a lot of methods ...
    ...

        /*! includes several bit-fields:
        - the magic signature
        - continuity flag
        - depth
        - number of channels
        */
        int flags;
    //! the array dimensionality, >= 2
    int dims;
    //! the number of rows and columns or (-1, -1) when the array has more than 2 dimensions
    int rows, cols;
    uchar* data;

    //! pointer to the reference counter;
    // when array points to user-allocated data, the pointer is NULL 
    int* refcount;

    // other members
    ...
};
```

when you are doing shallow copy, only the pointer , `data` (not the things `data` pointed to )would be copied.
no new memory will be allocated.
say , we have a `cv::Mat` called `a`.

> cv::Mat b=a;

`b`'s `data` field will be the same as `a`'s. 
No new memory will be allocated for `b`.

But what about the following code:

> cv::Mat b=a.col(1);

Here's a snippet code of `matrix.cpp` ,  which including the implementations of cv::Mat functions :

```
Mat::Mat(const Mat& m, const Range* ranges)
    : flags(MAGIC_VAL), dims(0), rows(0), cols(0), data(0), datastart(0), dataend(0),
      datalimit(0), allocator(0), u(0), size(&rows)
 {
int i, d = m.dims;

CV_Assert(ranges);
for( i = 0; i < d; i++ )
{
    Range r = ranges[i];
    CV_Assert( r == Range::all() || (0 <= r.start && r.start < r.end && r.end <= m.size[i]) );
}
*this = m;
for( i = 0; i < d; i++ )
{
    Range r = ranges[i];
    if( r != Range::all() && r != Range(0, size.p[i]))
    {
        size.p[i] = r.end - r.start;
        data += r.start*step.p[i];
        flags |= SUBMATRIX_FLAG;
    }
}
updateContinuityFlag(*this);
}
```

`cv::Mat::col()` will return a new `cv::Mat`,  it needs to call a constructor.
The constructor above is for constructing a `cv::Mat` with another `cv::Mat` reference,and a `cv::Range`.
Note that the `data` field is not a copy of the `data` field of `m` 's (`m` is the parameter passed to the constructor) `data`.

so,for my question..
 the `data` fields of `a` and `b` are different!